# How can I enable Apple iOS Fast Charge Support?

Tags: linux-kernel, iphone

There's been news that [Linux 5.7 supports configuring "USB Fast Charge Support For Apple iOS Devices"](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-5.7-Apple-MFI-Fast-Charge). Now that Arch Linux is shipping 5.7 and I have upgraded to it, I decided that I would like to try it out. However, the most information that I could find was

> The apple-mfi-fastcharge driver will allow setting the power supply property via sysfs to "fast"

which doesn't describe how to actually configure the feature. How can I enable it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the apple-mfi-fastcharge driver is compiled into the kernel, as it is in Arch Linux, it will automatically be loaded when plugging in an iPhone. This may be verified by running `sudo dmesg -w` and verifying that the following message appears:

```
usbcore: registered new device driver apple-mfi-fastcharge
```

(note: this will only happen once per boot. Run `sudo dmesg | grep apple-mfi-fastcharge` to see if it has been loaded at all in the past)

Now, you may tell the driver to enable fast charging:

```bsh
sudo tee /sys/class/power_supply/apple_mfi_fastcharge/charge_type <<< Fast
```

You will need to do this every time the device is unplugged and plugged back in. To avoid that, you may create a udev rule by creating the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-iphone-fastcharge.rules` with the following contents:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="iPhone", RUN+="/usr/bin/env sh -c 'echo Fast > /sys/class/power_supply/apple_mfi_fastcharge/charge_type'"
```

Comment: If you want to fast charge an iPad, you can use `ENV{ID_MODEL}=="iPad"` to trigger the script.

Comment: Instead of matching on the model, it might make more sense to match on the driver (`DRIVER=="apple-mfi-fastcharge"`) or the power supply device (`SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ACTION=="add", ENV{POWER_SUPPLY_NAME}="apple_mfi_fastcharge"`). In fact, just set fast on *any* power supply device like https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/hadess/power-profiles-daemon/-/blob/main/src/ppd-action-trickle-charge.c.

Comment: So uh I played around the stuff a bit and it turns out on my udev it insists on a "change" event instead. The definition therefore changes to `SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ACTION=="change", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo Fast > %S%p/charge_type || :'"`. (The `|| :` is there to prevent spamming the log with errors on removal.)